# Downloading all lead data through oAuth2 API

Tags: javascript, rest-api, api, soap-api, bulk-api

Completely new to the Salesforce API. I'd like to simply download all lead and contact information from a connected user's account - that is, anything which has an "Email" field. I've only briefly used Salesforce before so I may be in way over my head.

I'm currently using the [jsForce](https://jsforce.github.io/document/) API wrapper for NodeJS, but everything in the docs seems far too advanced for my needs.

I'm trying to do a request like this:

```
conn.query("SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Leads", function(err, result) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err); }
        console.log("total : " + result.totalSize);
        console.log("fetched : " + result.records.length);
        console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null));

      });
```

However, this gets me the result:

> Object type 'Leads' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a
>   custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name.
>   Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate
>   names.] name: 'INVALID_TYPE', errorCode: 'INVALID_TYPE' }

Knew it wouldn't be that easy. However, looking in my Salesforce account (my organisation is called "Warm") I can see that I do have plenty of leads and they all have email addresses under the column "Email":

[image]

Clearly I'm doing something very wrong. I'd like to download all leads, opportunities, contacts, orders etc but I barely know where to start / the Salesforce API docs have been no help at all (I've been reading for a couple of hours but it's all very theoretical and mostly Java based!)

Any idea what I can do to simply bulk download Salesforce data through an oAuth2 authenticated API call?

Answer (score 3):

Your query fails because your object name (Lead**s**) is wrong. 
You must use object names in singular.

Instead of:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Leads
```

Try:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Lead
```

As far as i know all salesforce API's can be used with oauth2 tokens, just use the access token as session id.

If you expect a lot of data you should consider to use the bulk API (JSForce contains an [implementation](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#bulk-api)).

As an overview which API you should use for certain use cases, take a look at [Which API Should I Use?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm)